# SQL Server EXEC OUTPUT always NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using an EXEC statement and the OUTPUT is always NULL. This is an issue for me. I need some way of identifying whether or not an INSERT statement succeeded. Alternatively, I could remove the @bogusTable and INSERT portion of the query and just test if the underlying SELECT statement gathered any results, but I always got NULL on that OUTPUT as well.

Here is the query:

```
SET @mainQuery = '
                DECLARE @bogusTable TABLE(
                    someField VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
                );

                INSERT INTO @bogusTable SELECT someField FROM someTable WHERE anINT = ' @randINT

EXEC sp_executesql @mainQuery, N'@tempParam INT OUTPUT', @tempParam=@someInt OUTPUT

IF (@someInt IS NULL)
BEGIN
    --This always executes even when the INSERT statement in @mainQuery doesn't insert anything
END
```

Comment: That's not how you should be adding `@randINT` to your executed sql. Where do you set a value for `@tempParam`? I see the declaration, and the expectation of output, but where in the executed script does it assign a value to `@tempParam`?

Comment: And if you're going to the effort of using `sp_executesql` with parameters, why are you still doing crude string concatenation to inject the value of `@randInt` into it?

Comment: If you add a `DECLARE @tempParam INT` above everything, it still outputs NULL every time.
Also, I have reasons for needing `@mainQuery` to have `@randInt` injected into it that are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here in the first place? From what is posted there is no need for dynamic sql at all.

Comment: @SeanLange See above comment.

Comment: We're asking you to *look* at `@mainQuery` it doesn't even *attempt* to interact with a `@tempParam` parameter - so by what magic are you expecting it to become set when `@mainQuery` is executed.

Comment: So what are you trying to do then? This dynamic sql seems way over complicated and your parameter is not mentioned at all inside the dynamic sql. It can't possibly ever be anything but null.

Comment: Ah ok. I have no idea. `@tempParam` is meaningless to me. All I need to know is if the SELECT portion of the query is successful. And once again, the dynamic SQL bit is beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting `@tempParam` in your dynamic sql, so of course it is null. You can set it to `@@rowcount` to see if any rows were inserted.

Try this:

```
declare @randINT int;
--set @randINT here!

declare @mainQuery nvarchar(max);
declare @someInt int;
SET @mainQuery = '
                DECLARE @bogusTable TABLE(
                    someField VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
                );

                INSERT INTO @bogusTable SELECT someField FROM someTable WHERE anINT =  @randINT;
                select @tempParam = @@rowcount;'

EXEC sp_executesql @mainQuery, N'@randINT int, @tempParam INT OUTPUT', @randINT=@randINT, @tempParam=@someInt OUTPUT

IF (@someInt > 0)
BEGIN
    --This will only execute if something was inserted
    select @someInt as row_count;
END
```

Notice, I also brought `@randINT` into the parameters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@BeanFrog was pretty close.

This is what I needed:

```
SET @mainQuery = '
                DECLARE @bogusTable TABLE(
                    someField VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
                );

                INSERT INTO @bogusTable SELECT someField FROM someTable WHERE anINT = ' + @randINT + ';
                SET @tempParam = @@ROWCOUNT;'

EXEC sp_executesql @mainQuery, N'@tempParam INT OUTPUT', @tempParam=@someInt OUTPUT

IF (@someInt = 0)
BEGIN
    --This executes correctly now
END
```